# Data Cleaning How to split Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

It has been sometime since I tried working in python.

I have below data frame with many columns too many to name.

```
  last/first    location    job    department
  smith john    Vancouver   A1     servers
  rogers steve  Toronto     A2     eng
  Rogers Dave   Toronto     A4     HR
```

How to I remove caps in the last/first column and also split the last/first column by " "?

Goal:

```
  last      first    location    job    department
  smith     john     Vancouver   A1     servers
  rogers    steve    Toronto     A2     eng
  rogers    dave     Toronto     A4     HR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `str.lower` and [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```py
df[['last', 'first']] = (df.pop('last/first')
                           .str.lower()
                           .str.split(n=1, expand=True)
                         )
```

output:

```
    location job department    last  first
0  Vancouver  A1    servers   smith   john
1    Toronto  A2        eng  rogers  steve
2    Toronto  A4         HR  rogers   dave
```

Comment: I want to remove all the caps.  for the first name and last.  sometimes people write john, John, JoHN, etc but need to clean it

Comment: @ReeseFitzmaurice I saw your updated question, and udpated the answer. Uee `str.lower` (or `str.capitalize` for reproducible first letter case ) ;)

Comment: what is "pop" i am getting an error msg. columns must be same length as key

Comment: @Reese pop removes and return the column at the same time. It is equivalent to `df['last/first'].str.lower().str.split(expand=True)`, then remove the column

Comment: how do i fix the error msg about columns must be same length as key

Comment: @Reese it likely means you have sometimes more than 2 words/names, try adding `n=1` as parameter to `split`

Comment: wow that works, i am still learning python what does n=1 mean?

Comment: @Reese, split only 1 time even if there are several spaces